# Database (PostgreSQL) trigger not preloading value in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I have a database trigger that is working perfectly fine.

```
    execute <<~SQL
      CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION set_next_invoice_number()  RETURNS TRIGGER AS $set_invoice_number$
        DECLARE current_invoice_number BIGINT;
      BEGIN
        LOCK TABLE tenant_sequences IN ACCESS EXCLUSIVE MODE;
        current_invoice_number := (SELECT invoice_number_sequence FROM tenant_sequences WHERE tenant_id = NEW.tenant_id FOR UPDATE);
        NEW.invoice_number = current_invoice_number + 1;
        UPDATE tenant_sequences SET invoice_number_sequence = current_invoice_number + 1 WHERE tenant_id = NEW.tenant_id;
        RETURN NEW;
      END;
    $set_invoice_number$ LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';
    SQL

    execute <<~SQL
      CREATE TRIGGER invoice_number_sequence_trigger
      BEFORE INSERT ON documents
      FOR EACH ROW
      EXECUTE PROCEDURE set_next_invoice_number();
    SQL
```

This block essentially generates and sets invoice number when a document is created.

Now, in Rails, when I do this, the field is always nil.

```
a = Document.new
a.save!
a.invoice_number == nil
```

In order to see the set invoice_number, I need to `reload` the object

```
a.reload
a.invoice_number != nil
```

or alternatively

```
class Document < ApplicationRecord
  after_create -> () { reload }
end
```

This is not very nice - is there a way to do this similarly to `id` field?

Comment: Yes and no. The way that ActiveRecord fills the id attribute on PG is that the database driver adds  `RETURNING id` to the insert query. If you were able to change the query to `RETURNING id, invoice_number` it would at least in theory contain your generated field. However ActiveRecord doesn't offer a straight forward way to change the returning clause and I don't think it would know to map the second return to invoice_number.

Comment: So in other words - its possible at least in theory but the solution would very likely be a lot worse then what you're currently doing.

Comment: @Jad I think you missunderstood the question; this sequence is not a replacement for the primary key column.

Comment: @max yep, got me ... need to read more carefully.  Rails wants all database transactions to go through Rails. I think it basically expects "a =Document.new; b = Invoice.new; a.invoice << b`  the only reason(s) against this should really be where you have other systems accessing the same data, or you can't centralise the code for Document creation, so can't control all users/inserters

Comment: What does your create action look like?

Comment: @Jad yeah pretty much. You could do this by using Arel::InsertManager to create the query  just like ActiveRecord::Persistence does and then add `RETURNING id, invoice_number` to the SQL. This SQL then needs to be executed manually and you would need to handle the return values and flip state in the model instance so that it behaves like its persisted. But by doing so you would have to replicate a pretty substantial chunk of ActiveRecord and you can't really resuse that much of the implementation as its mostly done in private methods or methods that are the opposite of modular.